# Is it possible to replace values in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know if it is possible in an SQL query to replace some values by something else, or if I need to do that in post-processing.

Let me explain. I have this table:

```
|username| accepted |
|--------|----------|
|  toto  |   NULL   |
|--------|----------|
|  foo   |    0     |
|--------|----------|
|  Rick  |    1     |
|--------|----------|
|  bar   |    1     |
|--------|----------|
```

I want to know the numbers of row per value of `accepted` (nullable bit). I'm running this query:

```
SELECT [accepted], count(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY [accepted]
```

Which should return:

```
NULL   1  
false  1  
true   2
```

Is there some way to replace the `accepted` values by more meaningful labels? Ideally I would like to have something like:

```
not_available 1
not_accepted  1
accepted      2
```

Is that feasible with SQL server 2008 R2?

Thx.

Comment: An alternative would be to let your application handle the literals.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a few values:

```
SELECT CASE [accepted] 
WHEN 0 THEN 'not_accepted' 
WHEN 1 THEN 'accepted '
ELSE 'not_available' END AS accepted
, count(*) 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY CASE [accepted] 
WHEN 0 THEN 'not_accepted' 
WHEN 1 THEN 'accepted '
ELSE 'not_available' END
```

Comment: in fact I get an error with the GROUP BY condition: "Column 'ValidationStats.accepted' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause". However that works fine with simply GROUP BY [accepted].

Comment: can you post the code? I runned the exact code against sample data and it is working

Comment: SELECT case [updateaccepted] 
when 0 then 'not accepted'
when 1 then 'accepted'
else 'not available' end
, COUNT(*)
FROM ValidationStats
GROUP BY CASE [updateaccepted]
WHEN 0 THEN 'not accepted' 
WHEN 1 THEN 'accepted '
ELSE 'not available' END

Comment: Try: SELECT CASE [updateaccepted] 
WHEN 0 THEN 'not accepted' 
WHEN 1 THEN 'accepted ' 
ELSE 'not available' END
, COUNT(*) 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY CASE [updateaccepted] 
WHEN 0 THEN 'not accepted' 
WHEN 1 THEN 'accepted ' 
ELSE 'not available' END

Comment: There was an error in the group by - you had an extra space character in literal accepted: WHEN 1 THEN 'accepted '

Comment: When you use CASE exoression's, copy-paste the code just to make sure they are identical

Answer (score 3):

Use a CASE

```
SELECT
    CASE [accepted]
       WHEN 1 THEN 'accepted'
       WHEN 0 THEN 'not_accepted'
       ELSE 'not_available' --NULL
    END AS [accepted], count(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY --try [accepted] by itself first
    CASE [accepted]
       WHEN 1 THEN 'accepted'
       WHEN 0 THEN 'not_accepted'
       ELSE 'not_available' --NULL
    END
```

You may have to use the whole CASE in the GROUP BY. Unless you do this

```
SELECT
    CASE [accepted]
       WHEN 1 THEN 'accepted'
       WHEN 0 THEN 'not_accepted'
       ELSE 'not_available' --NULL
    END AS [accepted], CountOfAccepted
FROM
   (SELECT [accepted], count(*) AS CountOfAccepted
    FROM my_table GROUP BY [accepted]) foo
```

Comment: As I understood it, there is no Syntactic need to GROUP BY the whole CASE statement.  It would only be Functionally required if two or more value in the Accepted field mapped to the same string (To avoid that string appearing multiple times in the final result set).

Comment: @Dems: probably, can't recall when SQL Server nags at me about this stuff

Comment: @gbn - for the "foo" version, should the second "count(*)" be something like "count(*) as count_accepted", and the first "count(*)" be "count_accepted" ?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    CASE [accepted]
        WHEN 1 THEN 'accepted', 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'not accepted',
        ELSE 'not available'
    END AS [accepted],
    count(*) 
FROM my_table GROUP BY [accepted]
```

?

Not sure if this is exactly right and don't have SQL Server available to test now, but should be something like that.

EDIT: aww, already posted

Answer (score 1):

yeah it is there ... you can modify your query as below -

```
SELECT decode(accepted,NULL,'not_available' ,1,'accepted',0,'not_accepted'),count(*) 
FROM my_table GROUP BY 
 decode(accepted,NULL,'not_available' ,1,'accepted',0,'not_accepted')
```

it should give output as you want..

may be decode function is not there then you can use `case`  over there..

```
SELECT 
case accepted 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'accepted'
    WHEN 0 THEN 'not_accepted'
    ELSE 'not_available' 
end,count(*) 
    FROM my_table GROUP BY     
 case accepted 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'accepted'
    WHEN 0 THEN 'not_accepted' 
    ELSE 'not_available' end
```

Comment: AFAIK SQL Server doesn't have DECODE.  Also, just as a way of saving on typing, you don't need to group by the full DECODE, but just the Accepted fieled, as the input:result relationship is 1:1.  You'd only need to GROUP BY the full DECODE if two or more different input mapped to the same output.

Comment: yeah by mistake i have posted for oracle ... it was clearly metioned that this is for SQL server... but as i am working on oracle i used to think in oracle prospective... 

post edited

Comment: Another fix to your code: use END in the end of the CASE statement